# Sybase ASE server start up without .cfg file

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

is it possible to start up the adaptive server in sybase ASE 15.0 without .cfg file being present? On each server start up, the message "reading .cfg file for configuration information" is being displayed. so, if i delete the .cfg file for the server i'm starting up, will i be still able to start up my server? will the start up **always** fail?

Answer (score 0):

The server should start fine without a .cfg file.  If the file does not exist when the server starts up, it will create it.

All this information is available in the documentation:

[ASE System Admin Guide - V1: Setting Configuration Parameters](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc31654.1550/html/sag1/X44828.htm)